# How to know that a form is valid on submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if the form is valid on submision :

```
$("#frm").on("submit", function() {
  // check if #frm is valid or not
});
```

How to check that ?

Comment: check for forms attribute like method & action using attr() method

Comment: What does "valid" mean to you?

Comment: Valid means that required fields are all filled.

Comment: For client-side form validation I usually use the jQuery validation engine: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine.  Needless to say server-side validation should also be present if possible :)

Comment: I make a field required by adding the `required` attribute.

Comment: @pheromix Then that is already taking place, if the user is using a modern browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I make a field required by adding the required attribute

After seeing that comment:

If the browser is modern, the form wont be submitted till the required fields are filled out.
So, if the code enters the handler, everything's fine and you can continue.

For older browsers:

```
var valid = !($('[required]').filter(function() {
    return this.value == '';
}).length > 0); // true or false
```